# Python create a complex dict from an SQL query

Tags: python, dictionary

In my project i run a complec postgresql query that create an output like thisone:

```
"25"    "000006"    "191215002N"    1   1.800000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    589
"25"    "000009"    "112036402G"    100 0.970000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008200I"    200 1.660000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008200N"    150 1.660000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008500V1"   53.5    1.930000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008500E"    61  1.930000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008500R"    56  1.930000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "213008200G"    50  1.660000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "113066592N"    20  5.583000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "199900502N"    321 0.725000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "199900602N"    360 0.680000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "217001100F"    1200    2.036000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "112031102N"    1200    0.198000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "112044602N"    800 0.600000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "112036402N"    800 0.500000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "113066702N"    800 0.600000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "113066602N"    800 0.550000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
"25"    "000009"    "112530780N3"   5000    0.178000    "2017-01-31 00:00:00+00"    318
```

now, using a for loop cycle in python i would to create a complex dict with subdict indexed by the last column groupped like this example

```
 {'<last column value unique>': {<second column>: {'total':<sum of 3 column>, 'fdata': <fourth column value>},...}, '<second unique value of last column>':  {<second column>: {'total':<sum of 3 column>, 'fdata': <fourth column value>}}, ...}
```

example with data:

```
{'589': {'191215002N': {'total':1.80, 'fdata': '2017-01-31'}}, '318':  {'112036402G': {'total':970 'fdata': '2017-01-31'},'213008200I': {'total':332 , 'fdata': '2017-01-31'},'213008200N': {'total':249 ', fdata': '2017-01-31'}, ...}, ...}
```

but i dont' understand how can with python create n my for loop a dict like thisone

Can someone help me please?

so many thanks in advance
A

Comment: I think it would be better if you include the expected output based on the input, rather than the number of columns.  Can you include the expected output?

Comment: ok add example with data, sorry and thanks